# How to make a HorizontalScrollView work properly when it's inside a ViewPager2?

Tags: java, android

Deep inside a ViewPager2 I have a HorizontalScrollView that contains a TableLayout. The problem is that the ViewPager2 often doesn't respond to touches when I scroll to the end of the HorizontalScrollView. I'd have to swipe multiple times in the same direction for the ViewPager2 to finally start detecting the swipes (sometimes it never even does). First here is the ViewPager2:

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/innerViewPager2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/innerTabLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Next here is the HorizontalScrollView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.ThreatMonitoring">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardBackgroundColor"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/frontLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/cardBackgroundColor"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/loadingTableTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginVertical="80sp"
                    android:text="@string/loading_table_data" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutContainingTable"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/most_recent_offenses"
                        android:paddingHorizontal="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6"
                        android:textFontWeight="600" />

                    <HorizontalScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <TableLayout
                            android:id="@+id/topLogSourcesTableLayout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingHorizontal="15dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                            android:stretchColumns="0">

                        </TableLayout>

                    </HorizontalScrollView>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

So here's how it goes: *ViewPager2 (horizontal) > NestedScrollView (vertical) > Lots of Layouts > HorizontalScrollView*